# How to replace a String from another String?

Tags: java, string

I want to remove some String from my original path, but I cant replace the another string from my original String

This is my code

```
String path="contentPath =C/Users/consultant.swapnilb/Desktop/swapnil=Z:/Build6.0/Digischool/";
String a=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("="), path.length());
path.replace(a, "");
System.out.println("a---"+a);
System.out.println("path---"+path);
```

I just want to remove `=Z:/Build6.0/Digischool/` from my original path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, since `String`s are immutable in Java, you have to re-assign the changes in a `String` to another reference:

```
path = path.replace(a, "");
```

Secondly, you are doing extra job out there. You can replace these lines:

```
String a=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("="), path.length());
path.replace(a, "");
```

with:

```
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("="));
```

Answer (score 5):

See [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
       ↑
```

It **returns** a new *object* of type `String`, you should assign the result:

```
path = path.replace(a, "");
```

However, you can simply do:

```
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("="));
```

Answer (score 4):

what all you need to do is

```
String a=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("="));
```

Answer (score 0):

String is a immutable class(Due to security reasons) you can not assign any other value to it once it is initialized.
You have to assign the substring to some other string object and then access it. Just change your code as shown below it will work.

```
String path="contentPath =C/Users/consultant.swapnilb/Desktop/swapnil=Z:/Build6.0/Digischool/";
String a=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("="), path.length());
    String b = path.replace(a, "");
    System.out.println("a---"+a);
    System.out.println("path---"+path);
    System.out.println(b);
```